# StringBuilder constructor accepts a StringBuilder object - why?

Tags: java, constructor, stringbuilder

The class `StringBuilder` defines four constructors, and none of them accepts a `StringBuilder`, yet the following compiles:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(new StringBuilder("Hello"));
```

Does this mean that the anonymous `StringBuilder` object gets somehow converted to a String internally by the compiler?

Comment: The internal `StringBuilder` is not assigned to any variable, but in the Java language the term *anonymous* has another meaning.

Comment: @manfcas That comment would be more helpful if you actually explained *what* anonymous means in Java, e.g. with a link to [The Java™ Tutorials - Anonymous Classes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html).

Comment: This isn't really Java terminology but `rvalue` is an accurate description.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A [`StringBuilder`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) is a [`CharSequence`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/CharSequence.html) (it implements that interface), and [there is a constructor taking a `CharSequence`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#StringBuilder-java.lang.CharSequence-). This is why the given code compiles:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(new StringBuilder("Hello"));
```

What this constructor does is simply initialize the new `StringBuilder` with the content of the given `CharSequence`. The result will be the same as having

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("Hello");
```

Comment: If you look at the source (I looked at Java 8), it doesn't call `toString()`. It calls `append(CharSequence s)` which calls the package-private `append(AbstractStringBuilder asb)` to copy the characters from the internal array directly.

Comment: @Tunaki Astounding... What a sneaky class... Now I know why sb.append(sb) works, too. Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

There is a constructor that takes in a `CharSequence` which is an interface that is implemented by StringBuilder and by String (among other classes).

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/CharSequence.html